# Which would be faster and which is correct php while inside if and integers?

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I have 2 while loops in an if then else if statement, the code works and all is good, but just a little question.

Take my first example, I declare on the while loop the true statement for it to execute,

```
if ($levelChange > 0) {
    while ($levelChange != 0) {
        echo '<p>You gained a level you are now ' . ($levelChange + $user['level']) . '</p>';
        $levelChange--;
    }
}
elseif ($levelChange < 0) {
    while ($levelChange != 0) {
        echo '<p>You just lost a level you are now ' . ($levelChange + $user['level']) . '</p>';
        $levelChange++;
    }
}
```

And my second example I don't,

```
if ($levelChange > 0) {
    while ($levelChange) {
        echo '<p>You gained a level you are now ' . ($levelChange + $user['level']) . '</p>';
        $levelChange--;
    }
}
elseif ($levelChange < 0) {
    while ($levelChange) {
        echo '<p>You just lost a level you are now ' . ($levelChange + $user['level']) . '</p>';
        $levelChange++;
    }
}
```

They both work but which one is better to use and why, also if anyone knows which could be faster please enlighten me,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP converts its arguments to boolean values where a conditional statement is expected. For numbers every non-zero value (`!= 0`) evaluates to true. The PHP docs for the [boolean type](http://php.net/types.boolean#language.types.boolean.casting) have a table with conversion rules for different types.

Therefore, `if($x)` is equivalent to `if($x == TRUE)`. There isn't any (measurable) performance difference between the two forms.

Comment: so zero in php will always be false and any positive or negative number will be true?

Comment: @cgweb87: yes, exactly. Any non-zero number is considered to be truthy.

Comment: Ok cool I understand now, thanks, I'll just use my personal preference then, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would say it's your preference.  I would probably use the comparison to 0, but that is just my preference because it is slightly more verbose to someone else reading your code.  There shouldn't be much a change in performance either way.